# if $f' = f - g$ and $g' = g - f$ and $f(0) = g(0) = 1$ find$ f$ and $g$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $f' = f - g$ and $g' = g - f$ and $f(0) = g(0) = 1$ find$ f$ and $g$.

To me, this seems to be a differential equation question.

$$f''=f'-g'=f'-(g-f) \rightarrow f''-f'-f=-g$$

Is this the right idea?

Comment: Try adding $f'+g'$

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ twice-differentiable?

Comment: Good point I am not sure.... maybe this is the wrong appraoch.

Comment: I only know that they are once differentiable.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Practice exam samples from a calculus 1 engineering sciences course. May I ask why?

Comment: Just curious, and making sure it’s from an ongoing contest

Comment: I think this question would be too easy for a Uni level math contest. Here is the reference: http://exams.skule.ca/exams/bulk/20159/MAT194H1F_2015_CALCULUS%201.PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin {cases}
f'=f-g \\
g'=g-f
\end{cases}
$$
Sum both differential equations:
$$(f+g)'=0$$
$$\implies f+g=k$$
Then:
$$f'=f-g =f-(k-f)=2f-k$$
Note that $f'(0)=0 \implies k=2$
$$f'=2(f-1)$$
$$\int \dfrac {d(f-1)}{f-1}=2 \int dx$$
That's easy to solve.

Comment: you could get $(f+g)'=0$ from adding both differential equations

Comment: Yes sure @J.W.Tanner but dividing both DE works fine too

Comment: dividing by $0$ is not acceptable

Comment: thank you it's corrected now @J.W.Tanner

Comment: What did you get for $g$?

Comment: I guess you 're right. i didnt calculate $g$. I will upvote your answer because it deserves it @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggested approach.  I left the details for you to work out.

$f'+g'=0$, so $f=-g+constant$.

Solve for $constant$ from $f(0)=g(0)=1$ and then solve $f'=f-g=2f-constant$ for $f$,

and then $g$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\begin{cases}
f' = f- g\\
g' = g - f \\
\end{cases}
$$

If we sum, we obtain:
$$
f' + g' = (f+g)' = 0
$$
this means that $$f(x) = k - g(x), \qquad \text{for some $k \in \mathbb R$}$$
Now,
$$
1 = f(0) = k - g(0) = k - 1 \implies k = 2 
$$

So the relationship is $f(x) = 2 - g(x)$.

Can you continue from here?